# C# парсинг даты формата /Date(milliseconds+(-)timezone)/

Tags: c#

Я знаю, что формат **"/Date(1335205592410-0500)/"** состоит из миллисекунд (сколько прошло с 01.01.1970) и часового пояса. Но я не могу найти название этого формата и стандартного способа парсинга. Если уже есть готовый способ, то не хотелось бы изобретать велосипед.

Подскажите:

1. Как называется данный тип формата даты?
2. Есть ли стандартный способ парсинга?

Я пытался распарсить вот так:

```
public override DateTime Read(
    ref Utf8JsonReader reader, 
    Type typeToConvert, 
    JsonSerializerOptions options
) {
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeToConvert);
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.GetString()));

    var result = serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);

    memoryStream.Close();

    return (DateTime)result;
}
```

Comment: `сколько прошло с 01.01.1970` - это называется Unix Time, в C# для работы с подобным есть методы `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds()`. А вот `"/Date(1335205592410-0500)/"` - это уже Json Date Format, придуманный вроде Microsoft и тут уже надо работать с десериализацией JSON для грамотного чтения такого. Например JSON.NET имеет [встроенный](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) механизм по обработке подобных форматов. Как дела у новоиспеченного сериализатора JSON от самих Microsoft -  я без понятия.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо большое за информацию.